# SyntaxError: Bad control character in string literal in JSON at position 219248 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: typescript, error-handling, vuejs3

I am getting above error when I try to build my vue 3 project with typescript

I tried applying typescript to my vue3 project using "vue add typescript" command. Actually my project was started as vue 3 and then I add typescript to it

Comment: Also I am getting "node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message port has been closed for the process 113806." along with